# how to get the output for specific column in this function from postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

what is the mistake I am doing here? I have tried to call the function like this, but getting 0 rows. please, anyone, suggest me an idea to get the output. Thanks in advance

input:

```
if input is given as select * from test2('township'),i have to get output as 
|township|--column name
|--------|
|1|
|3|
|7|
|9|
if input given as select * from test2('range'),output will be
|range|--column name
|-----|
|4|
|8|
|35|
|21|
```

below one is the code:

````
create type holder as (t text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test2(text) returns setof holder as
'
declare
  township holder%rowtype;
  range holder%rowtype;
begin
if township then 
for township in
 SELECT distinct "Township" as township
    from tableA
    loop    
    return next township;
  end LOOP;
  return;
  end if;
if range then  
 for range in
  SELECT distinct "Range" as range
    from tableB
    loop    
    return next range;
  end LOOP;

  return;
  end if;

end
'
language 'plpgsql';```
````

Comment: Could you provide sample data and the expected results?

Comment: Side note: There's no point in iterating over the rows of a query and `RETURN NEXT` one by one. You can use `RETURN QUERY` directly.

Comment: if i call township,values will come like
2
10
22
4  in row format.
if i call range,same like above values should come in row format.i dont want both columns at a time.i want it individually.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and/or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites, make sure the statements are complete and compile, don't post just mere snippets), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data as ASCII or markdown table (see ["How can I create a table in a post?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post)).

Comment: but i want all values in the tableA or from tableB @sticky bit